# Cannot pass data from a middleware to the next middleware in ExpressJS using passport.athenticate()

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

js and Passport.js. So I have this :

```
router.post('/login', middleware1, middleware2);
```

I also have this on my `app.js`

```
passport.use(new passportLocal(
    { usernameField: 'email' },
    function(email, password, done) {
        // working logic here
        // this returns a user object 
        // to the middleware1 if query is ok
        // returns error otherwise.
    }
));
```

And here are my `middlewares`

```
middleware1 = function (req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('local', function(error, user, message){

        // How do I get the 'user' object and pass it 
        // to the outer req or res?

        req.user = user; // <- is this ok? 
    })(req, res, next);

    req.user = user;

    next();
}

middleware2 = function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("user ", req.user); // <- this will obviously print null or undefined 

}
```

Now. How do I pass the `user object` from inside the `passport.authenticate()` to `middleware2`. I'm thinking of using `promise` something like this `passport.authenticate().then()` but I dont know the syntax. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: BTW those are router level middlewares.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
  app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

authenticate()'s function signature is standard Connect middleware, which makes it convenient to use as route middleware

Why are you wrapping the passport.authenticate() in another function?

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I would probably start without the misdirection

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), middleware2(req,res,next));

function middleware2(req,res,next) {
  console.log("user ", req.user);
}
```

If you want the req object passed to your function set the passport js options 'passReqToCallback: true '